# Is "catarolysis" a word? Whether it is or not, how might it be broken down into Greek or Latin derivatives?

Tags: meaning, etymology, nouns, prefixes, is-it-a-word

Some definitions I have seen are: 
"[catarolysis](http://www.allhotelscalifornia.com/kokogiakcom/logolepsy/ow_c.html#catarolysis) - n. - cursing to let off steam" 
 and
"[catarolysis](http://phrontistery.info/c.html): letting off steam by cursing"
 and
"[catarolysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=FtmZAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT35&lpg=PT35&dq=catarolysis&source=bl&ots=ndMeJN87lh&sig=I1npc2b5PVlZDd4RA_JFqZ-SD24&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRy-Oz9KvcAhVST98KHa5VD3E4ChDoAQgzMAI#v=onepage&q=catarolysis&f=false) /kat uh RALL ih sis/ n  The practice of cursing to let off steam"

So far I see that "lysis" means "to break down"; and "cata" means "downward movement"; but that doesn't seem to fully cover "cataro"...

Even if this is just coining for fun, how might the root words better match the definition?

Answer (score 2):

[It's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary?s=catarolysis) [not](http://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=catarolysis) [an](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catarolysis) [actual](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=catarolysis&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) [word](http://www.oed.com/), which means there's no established etymology. That said, what you're probably seeing is some 19th century latinate slang—[they just loved talking uppity latinate nonsense](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-soc1.htm)—that someone put into a dictionary as a lark and has since been unthinkingly copied by subsequent volumes. In any case, you can see [at Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=catarolysis&tbm=bks) that the only real 'use' it has is in collections of odd old words.

It's presumably based on the Greek [κατάρα](http://biblehub.com/greek/2671.htm) ("a curse", "cursing"<sup>¹</sup>) that shows up a few times in the Bible, plus the medical suffix *[-lysis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-lysis)* from Greek [λύσις](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BB%CF%8D%CF%83%CE%B9%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) ("a loosening", "an emptying"). There's no actual connection with steam, whose constant inclusion seems to underline that the word lists including it are just copying one another.

<sub><sup>¹</sup>Strong more specifically glosses it as "what *has* 'to go down' due to condemnation, i.e. the penalty-curse that results when God Himself curses... something."</sub>

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the root of the word is from ***cathar, a member  of [catharism](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catharism)***, a heretic  medieval movement, from which, probably, the notion of “cursing”.

Comment: I doubt it. To English speakers _catar-_ and _cathar-_ are not in the least confusible.

Comment: @ColinFine - it is not necessarily a "confusion".

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like a portmanteau of *catalytic* and *electrolysis*. Electrolysis often uses a catalyst and emits gases.